# How to compare two eclipse installations for missing features?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have two coexisting installations of eclipse on my machine. One is the plain eclipse and one is STS (Spring Source Tool Suite). For some strange reason (which would be too tedious to explain here) I have to use the plain eclipse. However, I want to import, use some of the plugins that already exist in STS.

Is there a way I can go about achieving this?

Comment: Its not just about STS. Its a generic question i.e. is it possible to list the differences between 2 installations?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to scan the filesystem for the plugins, the easier solution is to go to **Help** -> **About Eclipse** -> Click on "**Installation Details**". That should provide you all the installed plugins in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks - but does it provide where the plugin came for i.e. the update site?

Comment: I don't think so, it should list the provider names where you can manually google for the update site. Another way is to go to Windows -> Preferences -> Available Software Sites. I'm not sure if STS will list their update sites here since their plugins are most likely pre-bundled into the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install the STS-specific bundles into vanilla Eclipse.  You need to follow the instructions outlined here:

http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/doc/STS-installation_instructions.pdf

Look at the section called "Update site installation".

Comment: Thanks- but I am aware of this. My question is now generic - is there a way to compare 2 eclipse installations - whether STS or not.

Comment: What do you mean by this?  You just want to see which plugins are installed in one, but not the other?  Are versions important?  Can you be more specific as to why you need this?